# How to add uuid to log4j for logging into file?

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, logstash

I have this log4j2.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration xmlns="http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/config">
<Appenders>
    <File name="FILE" fileName="logfile.log" append="true">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%p | [%t] %l | message : %m%n"/>
    </File>
    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%p | [%t] %l | message : %m%n"/>
    </Console>
</Appenders>
</Configuration>
```

And my goal is to add in the RestEndpoint a unique id with uuid, but i dont know how to add to the xml file...or i have to configure it not in an xml file?

Comment: Read about MDC in Log4j

Comment: You can write like this   <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-7p %d [%t] %c %x - %m%n"/>.  Refer this [link](http://www.codejava.net/coding/how-to-configure-log4j-as-logging-mechanism-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your application, put the uuid in the ThreadContext:

```
ThreadContext.put("myUuid", new UUID());
```

I assume you know where the entry points in your application are where to put and remove these.

In configuration, extract the UUID from the ThreadContext with the `%X` pattern converter: (also added Loggers to your configuration)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn">
<Appenders>
    <File name="FILE" fileName="logfile.log" append="true">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%p | [%t] %l | id: %X{myUuid} | message : %m%n"/>
    </File>
    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%p | [%t] %l | id: %X{myUuid} | message : %m%n"/>
    </Console>
</Appenders>

<Loggers>
  <Root level ="trace">
    <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" />
    <AppenderRef ref="FILE" />
  </Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: You can also use Mapped Diagnostic Context (MDC) if you are not using Log4j 2

Answer (score 1):

Feel like there is another solution, which is easier, if what you need is just a unique id for each log record. Check UUID in [Log4j doc](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html)
The only update is to change the layout in xml file is to add `%u{"RANDOM"}`.

sample xml configuration

```
<PatternLayout>
    <pattern>%d{DATE} [%p] UUID:%u{"RANDOM"} (%t) %c: %m%n</pattern>
</PatternLayout>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. It just adds `"%u{\"RANDOM\"}"` literally in the log file.

Comment: I guess, it should be `%u{RANDOM}`