# How to generate UUID per message in log4j's JSON Layout?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2, uuid

I need to generate a random string for a correlation key for each log message and I found that there is a way to generate UUID in log4j configuration file. 
There is a mention of `UUID` on https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html, but it doesn't say anything about how to use it.

I am trying to set this as a value for a key in my JsonLayout.

```
appender.rolling.layout.external-correlation-id.type = KeyValuePair
appender.rolling.layout.external-correlation-id.key = external-correlation-id
appender.rolling.layout.external-correlation-id.value = %u{"RANDOM"}
```

But that doesn't do anything. It just adds the literal string in the log message `... "external-correlation-id":"%u{\"RANDOM\"}" ...`.

How can I get a random string to set it in the log message? Is there a way for me to atleast directly call the `UUID.randomUUID()` in thelog4j properties file?

I don't want to use MDC for this and am looking for a way to do it directly from the log4j configuration file.

Any other help with this will be very appreciated.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43999342/how-to-add-uuid-to-log4j-for-logging-into-file

Comment: I saw it. I don't want to use the MDC to send variables. I am looking to see a way to generate it directly by the logger. The second answer doesn't work at all.

Comment: From the docs you linked the `%u{"RANDOM"}` would go into your formatting pattern (where you likely have similar patterns for log level or timestamp or logger name already). But I am not sure you can call this a "correlation id", because it will be a different UUID for every message, so there is nothing to correlate.

Comment: The key is just a name. I just want a unique key for each log message. I don't have any pattern format as I am using the Json Layout. Does that mean I can't use UUID as a value for the key?

Comment: It is an option for PatternLayout, so yeah, it does not apply to JsonLayout.

Comment: Why generate via logger? What would you achieve, probably you want to trace all logg statements "for a request"" and hence UUID should be same for this set ?

Comment: Whatever system you feed that JSON to (logstash or such) can probably also attach a UUID on intake, so that could be a workaround.

Answer (score 3):

I've done something similar in a JsonLayout in a KeyValuePair using a custom StrLookup.

The code below shows a simple example of returning a UUID every time a message is logged using a custom Lookup. One would add the ability to have different operations per key etc. but this works.

```
import java.util.UUID;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LogEvent;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.Plugin;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.StrLookup;

@Plugin(name = "dyn", category = "Lookup")
public class DynamicLookup implements StrLookup {
  @Override
  public String lookup(String key) {
    if("uuid".equals(key)) {
      return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public String lookup(LogEvent event, String key) {
    if("uuid".equals(key)) {
      return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Then reference the Lookup using double $$ to have the value evaluated every message instead of just once.

```
<KeyValuePair key="event_id" value="$${dyn:uuid:-}"/>
```